# How can I get my UISwitch to call this method? (using theos)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, theos

How can I get my UISwitch to call this function: https://ghostbin.com/paste/y2xrc when turned on, and return FALSE; when it is turned off. (im using theos to compile)

(I got the switch to show inside "CKTranscriptCollectionViewController" in the Messages.app (MobileSMS.app), and now I want it to do something when turned on or off which is what I posted in the link above).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ChatKit/ChatKit.h>
#import <ChatKit/CKConversation.h>

@interface CKTranscriptCollectionViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwitch *mySwitch;
- (void)loadView;
@end

%hook CKTranscriptCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    %orig;
    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 51, 31)];
    [mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:mySwitch];
}

%end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a UISwitch, you should add a target for `UIControlEventValueChanged`

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggle) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Substitute in your target and action accordingly. You'll need to check what the value of the switch is when the selector is called.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIControlEventValueChanged

Comment: im  not really sure how to do this? i know to add your code to viewdidload; but how would I get it to perform the action in the link i posted?

Comment: I would need to know more about your class structure and the actual objects available at run time. My guess would be to add a method to your view controller that toggles a property on the conversation object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[yourSwitchObject addTarget:self action:@selector(generateLegendaryMessage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 

- (void)generateLegendaryMessage:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog("Its gonna be legen...... wait for it ...... dary !!!!!!!");
}
```